# SuiteCRM API V8 Search by phone

Tags: php, mysql, suitecrm

I'm trying to connect SuiteCRM to 3CX trough Suite API.

So the first thing i try is to get search an account by a phone number

```
https://URL/suitecrm/Api/V8/module/Contacts?fields[Contacts]=id&filter[operator]=or&filter[phone_home][eq]=XXXXXXXXX&filter[phone_mobile][eq]=XXXXXXXXX&filter[phone_work][eq]=XXXXXXXXX&filter[phone_other][eq]=XXXXXXXXX
```

Test it, the system gave

```
"errors": {
   "status": 400,
   "title": null,
   "detail": "Database failure. Please refer to suitecrm.log for details."
    }
}Database failure. Please refer to suitecrm.log for details.
```

In the suitecrm.log i have

```
Mon Oct 12 20:57:37 2020 [][][FATAL] Mysqli_query failed.
Mon Oct 12 20:57:37 2020 [][][FATAL] Error retrieving Contact list:  Query Failed:  SELECT  contacts.id , contacts.assigned_user_id  FROM contacts  LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm ON contacts.id = contacts_cstm.id_c  where (contacts.phone_home = 'XXXXXXXXX' OR contacts.phone_mobile = 'XXXXXXXXX' OR contacts.phone_work = 'XXXXXXXXX' OR contacts.phone_other = 'XXXXXXXXX' OR contacts.deleted = '0') AND contacts.deleted=0 LIMIT 0,-98: MySQL error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-98' at line 1
```

If i run the query in mySQL without `98`, everything is ok (no result.s.. limit=0, but no errors).
I think the error is at the end of the query `-98`: but i don't what is cause it!
Is there someone with same issue?
Thanks

Comment: Error message is pretty clear so is SQL syntax - LIMIT takes one argument only. The query is broken. If this is not your code, report this to respective owner

Comment: Thank you Marcin! I contact Suite Forum to try to find out a solution!